# new to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, mamp

this might come across as something very basic, but I am having some trouble.
I am trying to turn a website I have created in HTML and create it in wordpress, I have been looking online at tutorials and all I have found are tutorials on how to create a wordpress website from a template, not from my own html.
So far I have installed wordpress locally using MAMP. I understand that I need to chop up each section of my website (header, sidebar, content, footer etc). Do i have to create the website in the 'themes' folder? (htdocs > mysite > wp-content > themes > mytheme) ?

I know this is a very general question, but help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Tom

Comment: You'd better try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Create a new folder inside your `wp-content > themes` folder and start converting html files to wordpress template and put it in this folder

You can learn more about wp themes  http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

all the best

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to chime in here just to steer you away from a 'gotcha'. The classic rookie mistake when you start building your own first Wordpress theme is to try to build it on top of the default themes that ship with Wordpress (namely twentyten and twentyeleven).

Don't do that - they are truly horrible themes to work with, and make the beginners job much harder than it needs to be.  Commercial WP themes are rarely built like those dogs.

If you already have all the markup then your best best is to grab the [HTML 5 Reset blank theme](http://html5reset.org/#wordpress) based on Chris Coyier's original blank theme and start building on that.

Much easier, cleaner and quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Everything mentioned below is fairly accurate. You have to create a folder inside of the

> wp-content/themes

name it whatever you want. From then you have to research the wordpress codex in order to be able to pull in content from the database and display what you want accordingly. Lynda.com have a great video from Chris Coyier himself creating his own custom theme with custom fields, category pages and much more. However you have to pay. There are many resources on the web you just have to find what you want in terms of loops etc.

To set up a page template make sure that you comment it at the top, then it will be available from your backend wordpress as a page template i.e..

```
<?php 
/*
    Template Name: Test Category
*/
?>
```

Remember that this is your friend. http://codex.wordpress.org/

Answer (score -1):

> Blockquote
>   Do i have to create the website in the 'themes' folder?

Yes you do. You can see by the basic theme installed in wordpress how the folder structure has to be. Your template definitley has to be in that folder structure in order to be choosen in the wordpress backend.

There is good software to create wordpress themes such as [Link to Artisteer Website]artisteer[1](http://www.artisteer.com/).